# Git - branch name same as a prefix of existing commit hash

Tags: git

I have a remote branch with a name that matches a prefix of existing commit hash in the master branch. I want to checkout this branch, but git will go for the commit instead. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

- The name of the branch is 'ce38'.
- There is also a commit with hash 'ce38a103b...'.
- The name of the remote is 'origin'

Comment: What is the actual name of the branch? What you mean by "prefix"?

Comment: The name of the branch is 'ce38'. There is also a commit with hash 'ce38a103b...'.

Comment: And what is the name of the remote? Is it "origin"?

Comment: @Agis yes, it's 'origin'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -b 'ce38' --track origin/'ce38'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/ce38
git reset --hard
```